# exclude the first word from a string in perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I have a string like below, string may extend more but i want to exclude only first word not next consecutive . words

```
at.below.card
```

I want the o/p look like below

```
below.card
```

Comment: `$string =~ s/at[.]//`

Comment: Thanks for your response, in my file each line doesn't start with word "at.", Please suggest.

Comment: i am using s/^\S+\.//; 

but it prints only second word, not next consecutive words

Answer (score 0):

```
$string =~ /.*?\.(.*)/
print $1
```

This matches the shortest string up to the first dot, and then returns you the rest in $1.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the first word with a simple string substitution.

```
$mywords = "at.below.card";
$mywords =~ s/^[^\.]*\.(.*)$/$1/;
print $mywords;
```

Comment: =~ s/^[^\.]*\.(.*)$/$1/; wow, it works fine as expected.. you really made my day very easier.. Many Thanks for your prompt response.. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you can achieve this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'at.below.card';

$string =~ s/^.*?\.//;
print $string, "\n";

$string = 'at.below.card';
print substr $string, ( index $string, '.' ) + 1;
```

Output:

```
below.card
below.card
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i got the solution